# Default value of function as a function argument

Tags: c++, function, c++11, arguments, default-value

How do I properly define a default return value of a function that is an argument of another function?

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
bool x( ... , std::function<bool( ... )> func ) { ... ; return func( ... ); }
```

I would like `x` to return `true` if it's called without the last argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as the default value of `func`, e.g.

```
bool x( ... , std::function<bool( ... )> func = []( ... ) { return true; } ) { ... ; return func( ... ); }
```